# When VmallocUsed in /proc/meminfo will increase

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, proc

I see the following fields in /proc/meminfo related to vmalloc.

```
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
```

So, i wrote a basic kernel module which allocates memory using vmalloc to find out whether the 'VmallocUsed' field updates to the  memory i allocated.

Here is the kernel module

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static char *ptr;
int alloc_size = 4096*1234;


static int test_hello_init(void)
{
    ptr = vmalloc(alloc_size);
    if(!ptr) {
        /* handle error */
        pr_err("memory allocation failed\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    } else {
        pr_info("Physical address:%px\t Virtual Address:%llx\n", 
                ptr+4096, virt_to_phys(ptr+(4096*1234)));
    }
    return 0;
}

static void test_hello_exit(void)
{
    vfree(ptr);
    pr_info("Memory freed\n");

}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

After loading the module, I don't see the 'VmallocUsed' incremented by what I allocate.

What is the use of 'VmallocUsed' and 'VmallocChunk' field in the /proc/meminfo?

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482772/proc-meminfo-says-vmallocused-is-0-so-where-are-my-kernel-modules-stored

Another thing with your code:

```
pr_info("Physical address:%px\t Virtual Address:%llx\n", 
        ptr+4096, virt_to_phys(ptr+(4096*1234)));
```

You cannot virt_to_phys() vmalloced memory as it is not linearly mapped.
You would need to use vmalloc_to_pfn and translate the page.